# document is not defined Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

В документации по nuxt приведен пример

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueNotifications from 'vue-notifications'

Vue.use(VueNotifications)
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что Nuxt использует свою системы плагинов, как bootloader для плагинов Vue и т.д.

Я пробовал манипулировать DOM из плагина, но document не виден

Файловая структура

```
Dialog // Root plugin dir
|-vue
|----index.js
|----Dialog.vue
|-index.js
```

Файл Dialog/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Dialog from './vue/index'

console.log(Dialog)

Vue.use(Dialog)
```

Файл Dialog/vue/index.js

```
const Dialog = {}

Dialog.install = (Vue, options) => {
  console.log(Vue)
}

export default Dialog
```

Выбрасывает исключение

> document is not defined

Так как манипулировать(вставлять элементы и т.д.) DOM из плагина Nuxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответы находятся сами собой, нужно указать nuxt чтобы операции с document проходили в браузерном окружении

```
if (process.browser)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Dialog from './vue/index'

if (process.client) {
  console.log(Dialog)
  Vue.use(Dialog)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помог пакет browser-env. В месте создания экземпляра сервера, нужно вызывать метод require('browser-env')(); Тогда появится полноценный виртуальный DOM и плагины, использующие DOM заработают